# Receiving parameter in controller action

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

My legacy code have controller action like this

```
[HttpGet("GetCar")]
public ActionResult<MyCarResult> GetCar(string carId)
{
   ...
}
```

I don't know how to hit this with provided `carId` value, tried with postman but without success. If I leave `carId` value from the postman request the api gets hit successfully.

I guess my question is:
**Shouldn't this code be refactored like this in order to get `carId` as a param value**

```
[HttpGet("GetCar/{carId:string}")]
public ActionResult<MyCarResult> GetCar(string carId)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to specify pattern that uses syntax for route constraints :string doesn't seem to be valid constraint.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-constraint-reference

Just specifying `GetCar/{carId}` is enough

Answer (score 0):

You are in right spot but, what you should do is check the postman values, are they correct? If yes implement the functions you created in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Route   http://+/api/GetCar/333

```
    [HttpGet("GetCar/{carId}")]
    public ActionResult<MyCarResult> GetCar([FromRoute]string carId)
    {
        ...
    }
```